# HMAC for only private API

Tags: kong

We have two type of API endpoints; public and private. Is it possible I use HMAC on only private endpoint?

```
e.g.

GET https://api.example.com/items ... This is public API. No need HMAC.

POST https://api.example.com/users/john/friends ... This is private API. It needs HMAC. We want to confirm that John send this request by checking HMAC signature.
```

The following is installation of hmac-auth plugin. It does not seem that it has public and private distinction.

```
curl -i -X POST \
    --url http://localhost:8001/apis/api.example.com/plugins/ \
    --data "name=hmac-auth"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and posted it to the kong github issue. https://github.com/Mashape/kong/issues/2120#issuecomment-281890169

(1) Create 2 APIs with different request_path (without request_host)

```
curl -i -X POST \
  --url http://localhost:8001/apis/ \
  --data 'name=example-items-api' \
  --data 'upstream_url=http://api.example.com/' \
  --data 'request_path=/items'

curl -i -X POST \
  --url http://localhost:8001/apis/ \
  --data 'name=example-users-api' \
  --data 'upstream_url=http://api.example.com/' \
  --data 'request_path=/users'
```

(2) Apply HMAC plugins for the 'example-users-api' API

```
curl -i -X POST \
    --url http://localhost:8001/apis/example-users-api/plugins/ \
    --data "name=hmac-auth"
```